# Python type hint: Intersection of types (class implementing interface)

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I have a python class defining an interface

```
class InterfaceFoo:
    pass
```

some abstract class

```
class AbstractBar:
    pass
```

and perhaps a concrete class

```
class Bar(InterfaceFoo):
    pass
```

implementing my interface (or, if you wish, both the interfaces `Interface Foo` and `AbstractBar`).

Now in some situations, I would like to have a type hint saying »I expect an instance of a class that is derived from `AbstractBar` and implements `InterfaceFoo`«. How can I do this in Python? Of course, I could go through my code and add all possible concrete classes that are subclasses of `AbstractBar` and implement `InterfaceFoo` but I think that's a very ugly solution.

```
def func(obj: AbstractBar implementing InterfaceFoo):
    pass
```

This is possible in other languages, e.g. Objective-C, where you can write `BaseClass<Interface>`. I'm wondering, if there is an analogue in Python to this?

Comment: depending on why you're doing that I'd either use overloads or a [`Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol)

Comment: see https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#rejected for why this might not be idiomatic in Python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is indeed the [`typing.Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol). However the challenge here lies in the fact that you want a combination of nominal subtyping (i.e. a type declared to inherit from another) and structural subtyping (i.e. a type has a certain interface).

The `Protocol` is defined in a way that prohibits simply using multiple inheritance here, because, as any type checker will be quick to tell you, *"all bases of a protocol must be protocols"*. So we cannot simply inherit from any `AbstractBar` *and* a `Protocol`. Details about this are outlined in  this section of [PEP 544](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#subtyping-relationships-with-other-types).

What we *can* do however is declare our abstract base class to be a protocol. Since it is abstract and thus not supposed to be instantiated directly, just like a protocol, this should work in most cases. Specifically, with the [`abc`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/abc.html) module from the standard library, we have the option of specifying an abstract base class without inheriting from `abc.ABC` by instead setting the metaclass to be `abc.ABCMeta`.

Here is how that might look:

```py
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from typing import Protocol

class AbstractBase(Protocol, metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self) -> int:
        ...

class SomeInterface(Protocol):
    def bar(self) -> str:
        ...

class ABSomeInterface(AbstractBase, SomeInterface, Protocol):
    pass
```

We can now define a function that expects its argument to be of type `ABSomeInterface` like so:

```py
def func(obj: ABSomeInterface) -> None:
    print(obj.foo(), obj.bar())
```

Now if we want to implement a concrete subclass of `AbstractBase` and we want that class to be compliant with our `SomeInterface` protocol, we need it to also implement a `bar` method:

```py
class Concrete(AbstractBase):
    def foo(self) -> int:
        return 2

    def bar(self) -> str:
        return "x"
```

Now we can safely pass instances of `Concrete` to `func` and type checkers are happy:

```py
func(Concrete())
```

Conversely, if we had another subclass of `AbstractBase` that did not implement `bar` (and thus didn't follow our `SomeInterface` protocol), we would get an error:

```py
class Other(AbstractBase):
    def foo(self) -> int:
        return 3

func(Other())
```

`mypy` will complain like this:

```
error: Argument 1 to "func" has incompatible type "Other"; expected "ABSomeInterface"  [arg-type]
note: "Other" is missing following "ABSomeInterface" protocol member:
note:     bar
```

This is what we would expect and what we want. The `abc` functionality is also preserved by using the `ABCMeta` metaclass; so attempting to subclass `AbstractBase` without implementing `foo` would cause a runtime error upon reading that module.

Just for the sake of completeness, here is a full working example, where `SomeInterface` is a *generic* protocol, to demonstrate that this also works as expected:

```py
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from typing import Protocol, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

class AbstractBase(Protocol, metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self) -> int:
        ...

class SomeInterface(Protocol[T]):
    def bar(self, items: list[T]) -> T:
        ...

class ABSomeInterface(AbstractBase, SomeInterface[T], Protocol):
    pass

def func(obj: ABSomeInterface[str], strings: list[str]) -> None:
    n = obj.foo()
    s = obj.bar(strings)
    print(n * s.upper())

class Concrete(AbstractBase):
    def foo(self) -> int:
        return 2

    def bar(self, items: list[T]) -> T:
        return items[0]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    func(Concrete(), ["a", "b", "c"])
```

---

It is important to note that there is no way around defining a "pure" `SomeInterface` protocol. We cannot simply have a `SomeInterface` class that we can both instantiate *and* use it as a protocol. That is in the nature of these things.

Intersection types as such do not (yet) exist in Python as far as I know, so this structural approach is the best we can do.

Comment: That’s a great deal of extra keyboard use for the promise of static duck typing :-/