# What are the correct mypy hints for this generic classmethod?

Tags: python, generics, types, mypy

I have a series of classes that looks like this

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", bound="A")
U = TypeVar("U", bound="ThirdPartyClass")

class ThirdPartyClass:
    """
    This is from a third-party library and I don't control the implementation.
    """
    @classmethod
    def create(cls: type[U]) -> U:
        return cls()

class A(ABC):
    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def f(cls: type[T]) -> T:
        pass

class B(ThirdPartyClass, A):
    @classmethod
    def f(cls) -> T:
        return cls.create()
```

When I run mypy on this module, I get two errors for the last two lines

> error: A function returning TypeVar should receive at least one argument containing the same Typevar
>
> error: Incompatible return value type (got "B", expected "T")

In my mind, neither of these are valid.

For the first one, `B.f` *does* receive an argument containing the Typevar—it receives a `type[B]` and since `B` inherits from `A`, and `T` is bound by `A`, `type[B]` is valid here.

Similarly for the second one, the return type of `B` should be fine because `B` inherits from `A`, and `A` is the bound for `T`.

What types should I be using here to prevent mypy from failing?

Comment: `def f(cls: type[U]) -> U:` should work. *"B.f does receive an argument containing the Typevar"* - this is wrong, because you leave `cls` untyped. By default `cls` as first arg of classmethod resolves to `type[B]`, and never - to some type variable. Type variables used as return type must be present in at least one of arguments - otherwise they should be replaced with the upper bound or eliminated in some other way. You're probably asking about Intersection type, but there is no  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74320095/python-type-hint-intersection-of-types-class-implementing-interface).

Comment: Okay, makes sense. I changed some of the type variables to the bound class and things are working now.